# Effective nuclear charge and repulsion of electrons

Tags: electrons

[Effective nuclear charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_nuclear_charge) increases across a period. This is justified because number of protons increase in nucleus across a period, and there's no change in the number of "shielding" electrons. However, wouldn't valence electrons repulse each other? Why does this repulsion not seem to matter for effective nuclear charge?

Comment: for those who haven't seen it before (I hadn't, at least not recently) https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pKaH.png

Comment: They do, it's a reasonable approximation because valence electrons occupy a common shell further from the nucleus than the core electrons.